# 4x4 chessboard, bishops and knights are removed, 4 moves to checkmate

Tags: chess, poetry

> Four-by-four chessboard
>   Bishops and knights are removed
>   Four moves to checkmate

Minor spoiler:

> Many ways to win
>  I counted nine solutions
>  But one is special

Source: Me, I think this website needs more haiku :)

Comment: there's not enough room for 8 pawns aside.  can i assume 4 pawns a side are missing too?

Comment: No further comment / Time for explaining is past / Death of the author :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is the intended puzzle:

> [image]
>  **Mate in 4.**

Here's one solution (or four, depending on how you count), I think:

```
Take twice on b3.
B-pawn takes; discovered check.
Queen to a2, mate.
```

Or in a more common notation:

> ```
>  1. axb3+  Qxb3
>  2. cxb3+  Kxb3
>  3. bxa3+  Kc4
>  4. Qa2#
> ```
>
> If `2. - Kb4?` instead, then `3. bxc3#`

After ruling out pretty much everything else, here are four more solutions: (found the special one before these, but saving it for last in order to maintain dramatic tension..)

```
Start just like before.
Queen to A2 on move three,
then mate with a pawn
```

> ```
>  1. axb3+  Qxb3   (again, white can reorder the first two moves)
>  2. cxb3+  Kxb3
>  3. Qa2+   Kb4
>  4. bxc3# (or dxc3#)
> ```

And finally, the special one:

```
Sac queen on d3:
Exclamation marks galore.
Easy mate in two.
```

> ```
>  1. cxd3+!  Rxd3
>  2. Qxd3+!! Kxd3
>  3. dxc3+   Kc4
>  4. Rd4#
> ```

Comment: Correct, that's one. Actually, that's two. The original notation can be translated into common notation two ways.

Comment: Changing the second line to "b-pawn takes: discovered check" brings that up to four, even :-)

Comment: That's right, plus the nice one makes five, so you've got most of them!

Comment: ... And now nine. Well done! And extra exclamation points for your notation!!